# Выдрать логин и пароль Dial-up

Tags: телефония

Я приконнектил компьютер к телефону. Подскажите, как выдрать логин и пароль от Dial-up подключения.

Answer (score 1):

http://soft.oszone.net/program/7148/Dialupass/Ты об этом?

Answer (score 0):

Простите, вопрос не понятен. Если Вы имеете ввиду какой набрать логин пароль, то это зависит от провайдера...